# Can't put a white line in between head and body html

Tags: html

I am coding in HTML and am trying to make a white line or break between the head and body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {background-color: white;}
        head {background-color: palegreen;}
        table {height: 60px; width: 100%;}
        th {background-color: white; border: 20px darkgreen; border-radius: 50px;}
        body {background-color: palegreen;}
    </style>
    <title>(Insert Title)</title>
    <div class="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%"><a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)<a></th>
                <th width="80%"><a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)<a></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)</a>
    <br>
    <a href="(Insert Link)"(Insert Link)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using margins and putting p and br tags between the  and  tags but nothing is working.

please ignore the (Insert Link) and (Insert Title).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It should be `<br />` and not `<br>`

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036, In HTML, it will be <br> only

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` instead of `<br>`.

Perhaps you want to place it after the `</head>`, and before the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

adding `margin-top : 50 px` to style on body works and div tag should be part of body instead of head.

Code should look like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {background-color: white;}
        head {background-color: palegreen;}
        table {height: 60px; width: 100%;}
        th {background-color: white; border: 20px darkgreen; border-radius: 50px;}
        body {background-color: palegreen;margin-top:50px}
    </style>
    <title>(Insert Title)</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
 <div class="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%"><a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)<a></th>
                <th width="80%"><a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)<a></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)</a>
    <br>
    <a href="(Insert Link)">(Insert Link)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) element (not to be confused with [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)) is invisible, it's only there to declare meta information, scripts, stylesheets and such. On a website you can only see things that are inside the [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) element. Logically, there can be ny kind of space beteween `<head>` and `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your page content should be stored in the `<body>` tag. And there you can manipulate content with tags like `<br>` or CSS styles. Check the documentation what is `<head>` an HTML document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Head